# Setting a new counter to be nested under Chapter number

Tags: chapters, indexing, counters

In my thesis, I'm using a hack in a `sty` file that adds margin notes with entries in the Index, like so:

```
\newcommand{\thenota}{\thechapter.{\it \alph{notas}}.}
\newcommand{\nota}[1]{\stepcounter{notas}\marginpar{%
    \scriptsize \thenota\ #1%
    \index{%
        Nota de margem!{\thenota}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

This one works fine when I add `\newcounter{notas}[chapter]` after `\begin{document}`: Entries appear in the Index as "Nota de margem 4.a." as expected.

After a while, I decided to add another class of sidenotes, with the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\themudanca}{\thechapter.{\it \alph{mudanca}}.}
\newcommand{\mudanca}[1]{\stepcounter{mudanca}\marginpar{%
    \scriptsize \themudanca\ #1%
    \index{%
        Alteração no texto!{\themudanca}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

But when I add `\newcounter{mudanca}[chapter]`, the output I get is "Alteração no texto 1" and I get multiple page entries, one for each first `\mudanca{}` in each chapter.

A MWE would be something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\thenota}{\thechapter.{\it \alph{notas}}.}
\newcommand{\nota}[1]{\stepcounter{notas}\marginpar{%
    \scriptsize \thenota\ #1%
    \index{%
        Nota de margem!{\thenota}%
        }%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\themudanca}{\thechapter.{\it \alph{mudanca}}.}
\newcommand{\mudanca}[1]{\stepcounter{mudanca}\marginpar{%
    \scriptsize \themudanca\ #1%
    \index{%
        Alteração no texto!{\themudanca}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{notas}[chapter]
\newcounter{mudanca}[chapter]


\chapter{First}
\nota{aaa}
\mudanca{bbb}
\nota{aaa}
\mudanca{bbb}
\chapter{Second}
\nota{aaa}
\mudanca{bbb}
\end{document}
```

Why do they behave differently if they are coded exactly the same? Clearing `aux` files didn't solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It will be easier to understand the issue.

Comment: Sorry, egreg, I forgot about doing that, but Red's answer below provides one, so I'll implement his example in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have first to define the counters and then use `\renewcommand{\the<countername>}` instead of `\newcommand{\the<countername>}` to redefine the way in which the counter print its value:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{nota}[chapter]
\newcounter{mudanca}[chapter]

\renewcommand{\thenota}{\thechapter.{\it \alph{nota}}.}
\newcommand{\nota}[1]{\stepcounter{nota}\marginpar{%
    \scriptsize \thenota\ #1%
    \index{%
        Nota de margem!{\thenota}%
        }%
    }%
}

\renewcommand{\themudanca}{\thechapter.{\it \alph{mudanca}}.}
\newcommand{\mudanca}[1]{\stepcounter{mudanca}\marginpar{%
    \scriptsize \themudanca\ #1%
    \index{%
        Alteração no texto!{\themudanca}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\nota{aaa}
\mudanca{bbb}
\nota{aaa}
\mudanca{bbb}
\chapter{Second}
\nota{aaa}
\mudanca{bbb}
\end{document}
```

The problem in your code is that you define the command `\themudanca` and **then** you define the counter `mudanca` that overwrites the command `\themudanca` giving it the default value of printing the counter number as an arabic number.

In the first case this does not happen because you call the counter `notas` while the command you define at the beginning is `\thenota` and not `thenotas`.

I hope it's clear...

Comment: Thanks.  So the command `\themudanca` is created automatically when I add the counter `mudanca`? Didn't know that. 

I Also didn't know that you could set new counters before `\begin{document}` even though now it makes perfect sense since all other coutners are defined by `cls` and `sty` files.

Thanks again.

Comment: @EltonCarvalho exactly